Adding watermark to document
How can I add the grey text to make my LaTeX look better like in this picture? I have made numerous Google searches but it doesn't give me expected results.


Do I understand you correctly, you just want to put some grey text in the background?

To me it's not clear if the OP actually wants the watermark in front of the text or behind it, and it has no code, so I'll vote to close as unclear instead of the proposed duplicate.


You just need color or xcolor package for color, and graphicx for rotation:
Then place the text in the shipout/background hook.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}
{\put(200,-.7\textheight){\rotatebox{45}{%
        \Huge\textcolor[gray]{0.6}{SOME GREY TEXT}}}}
\begin{document}

text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text

\bigskip

text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text

\bigskip

text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text

\bigskip

text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text
text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text \ldots\ text

\end{document}


You can use the shipout/background hook to place arbitrary content into the background of the page. Inside that hook you can place anything that you could place inside a picture environment, so \put can be used to position stuff on the page (the point (0,0) is in the upper left corner of the page).
The following then uses xcolor for your text color, and adjustbox to scale and rotate the contents. The actual placement of \mywatermark requires no packages whatsoever and is guaranteed to be at the center of the page regardless of the contents of \mywatermark (provided that \mywatermark doesn't (excessively) overprint its bounding box).
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand\zerosizecentered[1]
  {\makebox[0pt][c]{\smash{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr\depth-\height\relax}{#1}}}}
% this adds the contents of \mywatermark to the background of each page exactly
% in the center of that page
\AddToHook{shipout/background}
  {\put(.5\paperwidth,-.5\paperheight){\zerosizecentered{\mywatermark}}}

% the contents of whatever we place centred on the page
\newcommand\mywatermark
  {%
    % rotate 60 degrees and scale to maximum size of
    % 0.8\paperwidth times 0.8\paperheight
    \adjustbox
      {rotate=60, width=.8\paperwidth, max height=.8\paperheight}
      {\textcolor{gray!50}{\huge\bfseries Whatever}}%
  }

\begin{document}
\duckument
\end{document}



You can use my recently updated magicwatermark package. https://ctan.org/pkg/magicwatermark
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{magicwatermark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\MagicWatermark{%
    setup = {
        pages = {*},
        content = {Watermark Text.},
        style = {text = gray!80, scale = 5, rotate = 45, font = \bfseries}
    }
}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\[
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]

\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}



why does you package uses everypage-1x which patches latex internals and is only there for compability reasons?

Maybe it's a historical legacy, I will optimize it in the next version, thanks!

@ljguo your package also defines functions that should be protected without said protection.

Can you describe it in more detail? I'd love to hear feedback and improve it.

I'm not sure, why no one referred the simple package draftwatermark.sty and the MWE is:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetWatermarkAngle{45} 
\SetWatermarkLightness{.8} 
\SetWatermarkFontSize{10cm} 
\SetWatermarkScale{5} 
\SetWatermarkText{{DRAFT}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\[
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]

\lipsum[3-4]


\end{document}



Your \tt should've been a \texttt. Also note that \tt doesn't take an argument but is a switch, and shouldn't be used anymore.

Sorry, missed to delete '\tt`, now updated, thanks for pointing this
